# Wordpress and background-image

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

My background image is not showing without a fixed height.

My code is as follows

```
<div class="site-branding"> 
  <div class="main-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.main-image{
  background-image:url('/nonprofit/wpcontent/uploads/2015/04/image1.jpg');
  background: url('image1.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:600px;
  }
```

is there a solution to get this working without a fixed height?

Comment: use `min-height: 600px;` for `<div class="main-image">` Now there is no content in this div so the height is zero

Comment: `background-image` is being overwritten by `background`. And as the answer below says, its an empty `<div>` so you need to give it a height. (at the least a `min-height`)

Answer (score 0):

Empty `<div>` are going to be 0px in height, so you have to specify a height.

Try putting some text in there and you will see your image show up without specifying the height.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't achieve this in any circumstances, All you should do is check if the content inside the div is good enough to show up the image. I not you must use a fixed **height** or **min-height**